# Wordpress Update 4.3.1

Tags: wordpress-version

Hello there i have updated the wordpress to 4.3.1

now its showing me the following error please help

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home1/dcp1997/public_html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the line causing the problem for you.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content');
```

this could be get_option('siteurl') is not a string. please check what you having at `wp-option` table and `siteurl` row.

If possible check what you are getting when you run `get_option('siteurl');` this line

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer ;)